# Array won't print row data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got this simple PHP code to print a Column from a database and it isn't working unfortually. Any ideas on what to do right?
I've tried to work on the while loop I have in the if statement but no luck
**What im trying to get array to print like :

[image: What im trying to get array to print like]**

```
<?php
$input = $_POST['input'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "hawk_manager";
$password = "hawk_eyes";

try {
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=HawkCenter", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
    
if ($input == "RoomNumber") {
    $query = 'SELECT RoomNumber FROM rooms';
    $statement=$pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $roomnumbers=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $statement->closeCursor();
    
    while( $roomnumbers=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        
        echo "{$statement['RoomNumber']}";
    }
}

$conn = null;

    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, it should be

**1. Selecting multiple rows**

```
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT RoomNumber FROM rooms")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row['RoomNumber ']."<br />\n";
}
```

**2. Prepared Statements::**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT RoomNumber FROM rooms WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute([$id]); 
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

> OR

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT RoomNumber FROM rooms LIMIT :limit, :offset");
$stmt->execute(['limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset]); 
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row['RoomNumber']."<br />\n";
}
```